# Haskell reversing string and taking words out

Tags: string, haskell, reverse

Two questions.

With this definition:

```
peopletext = "everybody is happy"
```

would this code litterally reverse that string, so it outputs "yppab si ydobyreve":

```
reverse peopletext
```

Also, if it's not too much, I want to capture words that are over 3 charater longs and put them in a list. So, only "happy" & "everybody" would be outputted. Here is what I have been able to come up with so far, but I'm stuck now and real tired :(

```
length $ filter (elem 3)(words peopletext)
```

Comment: Why don't you put it up in `ghci` and see for yourself if it works or not ?

Comment: I don't have it on this system, I will have to do it tomorrow but since I asked a question I thought I might be able to get some clarification

Comment: moobean222: so [try it in your browser](https://tryhaskell.org/) with `let peopletext = "everybody is happy" in reverse peopletext`

Answer (score 1):

The correct function to get what you want is :

```
Prelude> filter (\x -> length x > 3) (words peopletext)
["everybody","happy"]
```